# Проблемы с Linux Mint Sarah

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Добрый день. Возникла следующая проблема, точнее их две:

1. после переустановки linux mint sarah ноутбук перестал работать от батареи, а сам показывает, что заряд ее 40% и идет зарядка.
2. так же, после обновления, не устанавливаются обновления. выбивает ошибку
   E: /var/cache/apt/archives/python-samba_2%3a4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.2_amd64.deb: подпроцесс новый сценарий pre-removal возвратил код ошибки 1

даже если убераю из установки самбу, все равно проблема остается.

Comment: Проблема странная. Предлагаю просто сделать реинсталл. Да просто чистую установку провести гораздо проще, чем тупо лазить по кешу минта. (скажу честно, у меня всегда были те или иные проблемы с аптом в минте, причём ещё во времена lm17)

Comment: Да, в общем так и сделал. Не мог решить другими способами, ничего не помогало. Но по глупости, не глянул и поставил сначала бетту новую...ничего не инстолилось, пришлось возвращаться на Сару.